# On the similarity form a matrix with $A^m=E$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a real $n\times n$ matrix. Suppose that there exists some positive integer $m$ such that $A^m=E$, the identity matrix. Show that $A$ is similar to an othogonal matrix; that is, there exists some invertible matrix $T$ such that $T^{-1}AT=B$ satisfies $B^TB=E$.

It is easy to see that $A$ is similar to the diagonal matrix in the complex field. However, what about the real field?

Comment: Think about eigenvalues.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown We consider the real field.

Comment: **Still** think about eigenvalues!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Would you please give some more hints? I was totally confused when we consider the real field.

Answer (score 0):

According to the last theorem on page 146 in ”A Classification of Matrices of Finite Order over C, R and Q”, the answer is yes: It is shown that a matrix of finite order over the real numbers is similar to a block diagonal matrix, where each block is either a 1x1 or 2x2 orthogonal matrix. 
Se the paper: 
Reginald Koo, ”A Classification of Matrices of Finite Order over C, R and Q”, Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 76, No. 2 (Apr., 2003), pp. 143−148
http://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/otero/DOC/AI/3219311.pdf